# What is C2 surface in CAD, what does C2 mean?

Tags: opengl, graphics, mesh, surface, cad

C2 surface/mesh is well-known surface in CAD/OpenGL. But I just want to know that what is C2 means ?

C means what ?

2 means what ?

C2 = acronym ???????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Continuous in the second derivative.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_continuity#Smoothness_of_curves_and_surfaces)

Generally you'll see it used when discussing [various splines.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline#Use)